# using list of async funcs in async for

Tags: python, async-await, asyncpg

I have function that execute all functions in list like

```
async def db_create():
    x = [users_table_create, element_table_create]
    async with pool.acquire() as con:
        async for creation_func in x:
            async with con.transaction() as tr:
                try:
                    await creation_func(con)
                    await tr.commit()

                except Exception:
                    tr.rollback()
```

funcs:

```
async def elements_table_create(con) -> NoReturn:
    await con.execute("CREATE TABLE elements(...);")

async def users_table_create(con) -> NoReturn:
    await con.execute("CREATE TABLE users(...);")
```

But I got exception that I need something with `__aiter__`, not `list`

Comment: There is nothing `async` to do in that line. `async for creation_func in x:` -> `for creation_func in x:`

Comment: Note that `-> NoReturn:` means the function returns *nothing at all whatsoever*, not even `None`. This is only appropriate when the function *unconditionally* contains an infinite loop or raises an exception. Use `-> None:` for "void" functions.